# rate limit tweepy paginator search_all_tweets

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm not sure why I am getting rate limited so quickly using:

```
mentions = []

for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, query= "to:######## lang:nl -is:retweet",
                            start_time = "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z", end_time = "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z",
                            max_results=500).flatten(limit=10000):
  mention = tweet.text
  mentions.append(mention)
```

I suppose I could put `time.sleep(1)` after these lines, but then it would mean I could only process one Tweet every second, whereas with a regular `client.search_all_tweets` I would get 500 Tweets per request.

Is there anything I'm missing here? How can I process more than one Tweet a second using `tweepy.Paginator`?

BTW: I have academic access and know the rate limit documentation.

Answer (score 0):

See [the FAQ section about this in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/faq.html#why-am-i-getting-rate-limited-so-quickly-when-using-client-search-all-tweets-with-paginator):

> #### Why am I getting rate-limited so quickly when using [`Client.search_all_tweets()`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_all_tweets) with [`Paginator`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/v2_pagination.html#tweepy.Paginator)?
>
> The [GET /2/tweets/search/all](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all) Twitter API endpoint that [`Client.search_all_tweets()`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_all_tweets) uses has an additional 1 request per second rate limit that is not handled by [`Paginator`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/v2_pagination.html#tweepy.Paginator).
>
> You can [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) 1 second while iterating through responses to handle this rate limit.

See also the relevant Tweepy issues [#1688](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1688) and [#1871](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1871).